# option tag value attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php file that creates a couple of dynamic drop down lists.

The 2nd drop down is populated by a SQL query using the value selected from the first drop down - this is done through a JavaScript function.

This works perfectly when items such as "Orange" is selected in the first drop down. However, if "A&P" is selected in the first drop down, the value that is used in the SQL query is "A". This is because the option tag value attribute only recognises text.

My question is, is there an easy way to get around the text issue to use special characters in the option tag value attribute? Or would i be best to rename "A&P" to "Apples and Pears"?

I'm not technically gifted at all so if there is a way to get around the text issue, please could any answers be "dumbed" down?

Thanks!

Comment: how your option tag looks like , you can use value attribute to set value as "Apples and Pears" and display A&P

Comment: plz give a sample of your select.

Answer (score 1):

> This is because the option tag value attribute only recognises text.

No, it isn't.

It is because either:

- The `&` character has a special meaning in HTML
- The `&` character has a special meaning in encoded form data (i.e. the end of the current key=value pair)

(Both are true, and your problem is almost certainly the latter, but you haven't provided a [mcve]).

When generating HTML, make sure you represent `&` as `&amp;`.

When generating form data, make sure you represent `&` as `%26`. The `encodeURIComponent` method will do this for you.